# Best way to bulk update a lot of single fields?

Tags: javascript, query, remote-action, bulk

I apologise about the title. Couldn't phrase it well.

I have this page with lots of rows. Each row has an input field representing a value of a sObject. Once a user changes a value into a field I catch that with JS and using RemoteAction I sent the ID of the sObject and the value to update in the database. This leads to a lot of single queries, so not good.

How can I avoid this. Obviously if I was to put a save button then I could just gather all fields at once and send them as a list. However I want to avoid the usage of the save button.

Is there a way to store the information into a batch or something and execute that let's say in 5 minutes after it was first populated? This way I can give the user time to keep updating fields and then bulk update them.

Comment: One of the solutions would be to create some global variable, called queue, and the use set interval (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) that would perform actual remote call with all the data from global variable, and then clean it

Comment: What's the problem with ththe single queries? Not limits, I assume.

Comment: @SebastianKessel in case if there are lot of guys who are doing massively editing, some limits (api calls) may be consumed really fast

Comment: API limits are all incoming. Outbound API calls from SFDC do not count against the limit... I'd like to hear the OP's reasons

Comment: Why all the focus on JS instead of OOB?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I would think performance would provide a compelling argument against many small and similar requests.

Comment: I don't know how this app works, the use-cases the OP needs, or the time requirements. We can both assume a lot but I really wanted the OP to elaborate on his needs. Sometimes a 2 sec delay on each operation (about what it takes for a RA to return) is immaterial. Sometimes it is a deal-breaker.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I was worried about the load many small requests would put on the servers + hitting any limits.

Comment: So, if the performance hit of many RA calls is not bothering you, you're fine. You won't overwhelm the servers nor hit a limit (at least not from the RA itself, there are other limits that you could hit, like the soql row limit)

Comment: @SebastianKessel I am sorry but I haven't run across the abbreviation RA. What does RA stand for? Also how can I avoid hitting a soql row limit then?

Comment: "Remote Action". :D 
You have a limit of how many records can be selected/edited at the same time. Make sure to keep your SoQLs under it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Surely

Here is how you can do it.

1) Record all the updates in json
2) Write java script function that call action function and pass recorded json
3) Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to call the JS function created @ 2)

Some points to note:
1) If user close the browser your last batch of data can be lost
2) if user navigate to other page again data lost can happen
3) Have you check remote object as alternate solution

Comment: Why is `setTimeout` relevant? Can you please explain in more depth?

Comment: The setTimeout() method calls a function after a specified number of milliseconds. so you can chain /schedule / call recursively to invoke auction function automatically after 5 min. Its same like action poller but in JS. let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I know what it does. What doesn't make sense is why you need it in this context, instead of just performing the action directly.

Comment: to call action function automatically after every 5 minutes as OP asked in question

Comment: @AdrianLarson calling the RA immediately is what the OP is doing and what he wants to stop doing.

Comment: My problem with this solution is as you have stated - what if the user closes his browser. That's why I was wondering if there was a backend solution instead?

Comment: also, you can not have more than 10 types of sObjects at once. You should take care of the number of types of records.